# stranges AttributeError: 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'rect'

Tags: python, pygame

```py
stf = pygame.image.load(path.join(img_dir, 'meteorBrown_small2.png')).convert()

ball_mini_img = pygame.transform.scale(stf, (24, 18))
ball_mini_img.set_colorkey(WHITE)

class Gates(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
  def __init__(self, y, h):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.image = pygame.Surface((400,15))
    self.image.fill((random.randrange(0, 33),random.randrange(0,41),random.randrange(0, 57)))
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.x = WIDTH/2 - 200
    self.rect.y = y
    self.lives = 5
    self.hidden = False
    self.hide_timer = 
    pygame.time.get_ticks()

    def update(self):
        #Show if hidden
        if self.hidden and pygame.time.get_ticks() - self.hide_timer > 1000:
            self.hidden = False
            self.rect.x = WIDTH/2 - 200
            self.rect.y = y

    def hide(self):
        #Hide the Gates
        self.hidden = True
        self.hide_timer = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        self.rect.center = (WIDTH/2, h)

...
```

Here just add to All_SpritesGroup

Here(below) all rights with TABs, but just code written here strange

```py
def draw_lives(surf, x, y, lives, img):
    for i in range(lives):
    img_rect = img.get_rect()
    img.rect.x = x + 30 * i
    img.rect.y = y
    surf.blit(img, img_rect)

    draw_lives(screen, WIDTH - 100, 5, gate1.lives, ball_mini_img)
    draw_lives(screen, WIDTH - 100, HEIGHT - 5, gate2.lives, ball_mini_img)
```

Comment: Thanks cause I dont know how do it :)

Comment: It is a typo `img.rect` must to be `img_rect` (in `draw_lives`)

Comment: Yes, Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testing.py", line 637, in <module>
    draw_lives(screen, WIDTH - 100, 5, gate1.lives, ball_mini_img)
  File "testing.py", line 470, in draw_lives
    img.rect.x = x + 30 * i
AttributeError: 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'rect'

Comment: Yes, thanks. img.rect must to be img_rect, thanks, thanks, thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: I really did not see this Error's code

Answer (score 0):

It is a typo `img.rect` must to be `img_rect` (in `draw_lives`)

(' What is the sap')
Thanks to Rabbid76

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.